# Python DLL vs C++ DLL

Tags: python, dll, cythonize

I have read various articles on web to develop some rudimentary understanding of DLL.

As I understand DLL's are binary files so if I am able to generate a DLL from Python script using `Cython.build` package, the DLL is going to give a speed up compared to original Python script.

If there is no C++ code optimization, will the DLL using `Cython.build` give the same speed as a native C++ code with same logic.

Or is all my above understanding false?

Comment: Why negative and close votes?

Comment: The Python interpreter is traditionally written in C. So when a binary is generated from Python code, it's really compiled C code. A competent C/C++ programmer should be able to out perform compiled Python code as the granularity of control in C is much higher than Python (think control over memory consumption). The advantage of using Python is that development is usually much more streamlined as there's more abstraction, and it's much faster to test scripted languages. Compiled Python isn't meant to compete with hand-written C (yet), but it does offer higher performance to traditional Python.